# Adding Profile Picture to Bootstrap/Foundation Navbar with Devise/Oauth?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, devise, oauth-2.0, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I've been researching online and havent found a guide on adding a profile picture to the navbar when using Oauth/Devise/Bootstrap or Foundation - Any advice/guides? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information to go off of here...

Where is this profile picture being stored?  Are you grabbing it from the user's Oauth account? Say from Facebook or Twitter?  or are you storing it yourself?

I would assume you are just trying to update the navbar with a locally stored profile pic once the user has signed in (is this correct?).

Bootstrap and Foundation are just JS and CSS libraries, they will influence your display, but not needed to display your profile pic, in general.

If you are using Ruby on Rails and Devise, you already have a helper method called 'current_user', which Devise provides for free.

If you wanted to display a profile picture in your nav bar upon user sign-in, you would then just use...

```
<nav id='nav_bar'>
  <% if current_user %>
   <%= image_tag("/assets/yourimagename.jpg", class: "foundation_or_bootstrap_class") %>
  <% end %>
  <ul class='nav_links'>
    <li><%= link_to 'Sign In', '#yourlinkhere', class: 'sign_link' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Sign Out', '#yourlinkhere', class: 'sign_link' %></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In this instance, the navbar will only update on page reload or redirect.  If you want to update the navbar with just javascript you can do that as well, but will require a little more detailed coding.

If you just use the Devise gem as it is first provided, you don't have access directly to Devise views or controllers, so the above code would go in views/layouts/application.html.erb above   .

Then the profile pic would be present in the navbar on any view even a devise view.

If you would like to influence the devise views and controllers, there is a way to bring these out.  The Devise Wiki provides details about this procedure here...

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

under 'Configuring Views' and 'Configuring Controllers'

I can go further in to detail and provide more code if you add some examples and more info.  Perhaps this already helps?

Comment: Thank you so very much. This is all great- I did mean importing profile picture from FB / Twitter account.

Comment: You will need to sign up with Twitter first as a developer here https://dev.twitter.com/.  They will provide you with some numbers to use on your site so that you can use Oauth.  You can also hard code your own personal sign in numbers so that you can test out how to use data from Twitter.  I have only used Twitter, I don't know Facebook's setup.  I know that Twitter uses Oauth 1 and Facebook uses Oauth 2.  The setup will be different.  What is more useful to you, Twitter or Facebook?

Comment: Lets say Twitter. I already have Devise and Oauth, as well as a twitter app set up and am only getting the users name at this point. Please see TinyURL.com/Railsapp - Goal is to get profile picture up somewhere. This is mostly just to learn more about how this works, for fun.